# Mongo find() does not work with multer to list all images

Tags: node.js, mongodb, crud, multer, gridfs

I have built a simple CRUD API for multer/gridfs to storage image files. It does work properly in terms of adding, deleting and finding certain image by it's name. However it does not list all the added files with find(). I am new to multer, so maybe I don't know something specific about chunks/files that makes this behave like that.

Here is my API for listing all files:

```
const Grid = require("gridfs-stream");
...
const conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.once("open", function () {
    gfs = Grid(conn.db, mongoose.mongo);
    gfs.collection("images");
});
...
app.get("/api/v1/files", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const file = await gfs.files.find();
        const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file);
        readStream.pipe(res);
    } catch (error) {
        res.send("not found");
    }
});
```

Here is error log for GET request:

```
.../WebstormProjects/irrisfileapiv1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:113
      throw err;
      ^

MongoError: file with id  not opened for writing
    at Function.create (.../WebstormProjects/irrisfileapiv1/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/error.js:59:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much experience with `gridfs-stream` or multer, but I think we can use some context clues to start figuring out what might be happening here.

The error message is:

```
MongoError: file with id  not opened for writing
```

Looking very closely, note there are *two* spaces here:

```
id  not
```

I am guessing this is not a typo. The code generating this message is probably generating a string such as:

```
"file with id " + fileName " not opened for writing"
```

So the file name that this function is attempting to use/open is probably incorrectly set to `null`. In your code we can see:

```
        const file = await gfs.files.find();
        const readStream = gfs.createReadStream(file);
```

This looks incorrect to me. The `.find()` function is going to return a cursor. But as far as I can tell from [the readme](https://github.com/aheckmann/gridfs-stream#createreadstream), the `createReadStream` function is expecting to receive a filter with an `_id` or a `filename`.

Also, the error message specifically references opening the file for *writing*. But the code snippets you've shared are just about read streams. So the specific line of code that is generating the error message you've reported may be elsewhere.